# Optional __ror__ data in python class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to have an object that I can call using normal `obj()`, but I optionally want to send it extra data using `__ror__`. The object should do the same, but only 1 time.

Something like this:

```
class ArithmeticTest:
    def do_something(self, param=None):
        print('do_something', param)

    def __ror__(self, obj):
        print('inside __ror__')
        self.do_something(obj)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('inside __call__', args)
        return self


a = ArithmeticTest()

{} | a('with ror')
a('without ror')
```

I want to call the `do_something` function in both cases, but provide `param` if called from `__ror__`.

The code above gives this output:

```
inside __call__ ('with ror',)
inside __ror__
do_something {}
inside __call__ ('without ror',)
```

But I want something like

The code above gives this output:

```
inside __call__ ('with ror',)
inside __ror__
do_something {}
inside __call__ ('without ror',)
do_something None
```

I've looked at the docs, but could not find any magic methods that is called "if not other arithmetic is used"..

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *"if not other arithmetic is used"* - what is the *expected* or desired output from that code?

Comment: `__ror__` is **not** the way to send this extra data. Just make it a `__call__` argument with a default value.

Comment: ``a(...)`` by itself cannot distinguish whether it is used as part of ``b | a(...)`` or a bare ``a(...)``. Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: This is syntactic sugar in another framework where this `|` idea looks good. I know it would have been better to use a normal argument. If `a` have no idea of knowing about this, then I need to go back to the drawing board.. thanks

Comment: Are you fine with adding any other syntax? For example, wrapping the entire expression ``run(b | a(...))`` or using a ``with ArithmeticTest() as a:`` block?

Comment: I really wanted to use it like the question. The "original" way isnt that bad either, I just want it to look better in my little use-case